# Kafka will connect in Java but not Python

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, cloudera, kafka-consumer-api

I am attempting to connect to a cloudera environment using Kafka and stream data from a topic. I have been able to successfully do this in java but not python. Python appears to connect but it unable to receive the logs. I don't believe my paths, or servers are incorrect because I have connect via java with the same information.

I have done this successfully before with another cloudera environment, in python, and I'm basically copying and pasting from that code. With that being said is it possible that there are some settings in cloudera for this environment that are preventing me from receiving the logs via python?.

```
with java:
  from java.lang import System
  System.setProperty('java.security.auth.login.config','<path to jaas.conf>')
  System.setProperty('java.security.krb5.conf','<path to krb5.conf>')
broker=['<broker1>:9092','<broker2>:9092','<broker3>:9092'] 
try:
  consumer=KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=broker,
                         sasl_kerberos_service_name='kafka',
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',api_version=(1,0,1),
                         session_timeout_ms= 30000,enable_auto_commit=True,
                         sasl_mechanism='GSSAPI',
                         security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT')
except Exception as e:
  message_consumer="Error  connecting to kafka"+e.message
  sendAlertEmail(message_consumer) 
  logger1.error("Failed to connect to brokers"+e.message)
```

To test the program I do,

```
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

When i attempt to access the environment it never makes it into the loop. However, I know there are logs for the topic.

Comment: Did you try to provide a unique group id? When instantiating `KafkaConsumer`, also include the following: `group_id='my-python-group'`.